# How to make a Line graph in cn1

Tags: codenameone

I want to make a line chart however I have pretty much no idea how to use the chart API. I have adjusted the code for making a pie chart in order to try make a line chart. I would really appreciate help with the implementation or if there is a tutorial on how to make a line chart that would be great.

```
    package userclasses;

import com.codename1.charts.ChartComponent;
import com.codename1.charts.models.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import com.codename1.charts.models.XYSeries;
import com.codename1.charts.renderers.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import com.codename1.charts.util.ColorUtil;
import com.codename1.charts.views.LineChart;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;

/**
 *
 * @author Robin
 */
public class LineGraph1 {
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildXYMSRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 30, 15, 0});

        return renderer;
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildXYMultipleSeriesDataSeries(String title, double[] xValues, double[] yValues) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset series = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        int k = 0;
        XYSeries xys = new XYSeries(title);
        for (int i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++) {
            xys.add(xValues[i], yValues[i]);
        }
 {

        }
        series.addSeries(xys);

        return series ;
    }

    public Form createLineChartForm() {

        // Generate the values
        double[] xValues = new double[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        double[] yValues = new double[]{20,26,31,21,44};


        // Set up the renderer
        int[] colors = new int[]{ColorUtil.BLUE, ColorUtil.GREEN, ColorUtil.MAGENTA, ColorUtil.YELLOW, ColorUtil.CYAN};
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildXYMSRenderer(colors);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setDisplayValues(true);
        renderer.setShowLabels(true);
        //SimpleSeriesRenderer r = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0);

        // Create the chart ... pass the values and renderer to the chart object.


        LineChart chart = new LineChart(buildXYMultipleSeriesDataSeries("Project budget", xValues, yValues), renderer);
        //LineChart chart2 = new LineChart(buildXYMultipleSeriesDataSeries("Project budget", values), new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer());
        // Wrap the chart in a Component so we can add it to a form
        ChartComponent c = new ChartComponent(chart);

        // Create a form and show it.
        Form f = new Form("Graph");
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, c);
        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree the chart package is pretty low level. We might want to offer something more "user friendly".

I suggest going thru the line chart demo code in the new charts demo which is slightly simplified: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/charts-demo-revisited.html

Check out the code [here](https://github.com/codenameone/Charts/blob/master/src/com/codename1/demos/charts/AverageCubicTemperatureChart.java) that produces this line chart:

[image]

Comment: Hi Shai. Thanks so much for the comment. I did see this demo and downloaded it however in the project, the classes say that import com.codename1.charts....  does not exist. How do I enable the charts package in the demo classes?

Comment: The demo source should be in the latest version of the IDEs so you should be able to see it under New -> Project -> Codename One/Demos in 3.5+ plugins.

Comment: Ah there we go! Thank you so much.